# Linux: One time message on login

Tags: linux, centos

I am looking for a command similar to wall but will deliver a message to users currently sshed in and if they are not logged in will display upon their next ssh login( but only once ). Context is that I may( not guaranteed ) have a network outage but not everyone on the machine(s) will have gotten the maintenance email and I would rather forward the email to all the users of the machine(s). Not looking to put a message in /etc/motd since that will put up the message upon every login.

Comment: What is the problem with getting this message multiple times upon login? Just remove it after the outage is done or definitely not necessary.

Comment: It's annoying to get spammed with countless messages when it's always the same thing, I guess that's the only reason.

Comment: That is pretty much the reason, I know I open up two or three shell sessions and quite a number of users login on somewhat spotty internet connections so getting hit with the same message a couple dozen times a day gets irritating quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a standard way of doing this: `news`.  In olden times this was a standard command, but these days it's a bit crusty and has to be installed manually.  The Debian/Ubuntu package you want is `sysnews`.

To use it,

- create a file called something like `/var/lib/sysnews/login-message` containing your message
- add `news` to `/etc/profile` (or equivalent for your users' shell)

When your users log in, they'll see the message the first time, but then `.news_time` is created in their home directory, and they'll only see news items that have been modified since the timestamp of that file.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I am looking for, just need to find a package for CentOS then. Cheers!

Comment: @VincentAlpha did you find the package for CentOS? I looked for a while but was unable to. Posting it here could help other future users.

Comment: @user3243242 Unfortunately not, and it seems back then I didn't even find the source (or consider building it from source); just checked a rocks server I sysadmin and no luck in the 7.0 repos either (the one for the question was CentOS 5 or 6).

Comment: @VincentAlpha thank you for checking! For anyone stumbling across this qusetion, I ended up implementing themel's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a global `/etc/profile` that you could do this from? Won't catch everyone and their weird shell of the day, but basically

```
if [ ! -e "$HOME/.saw-the-message" ];
   echo "The system will go down tomorrow, but I will never tell you again!"
   touch $HOME/.saw-the-message
fi
```

Problems:

- you'll have to clean up the lock files afterwards
- misses some people who use `$weird_shell`

Comment: Dont you mean if [ ! -e "$HOME/.saw-the-message" ];  ?